# Git's ignore inversion rule doesn't work as I expect

Tags: git, bower

I have a tree:

```
- bower_components
  - jquery
    - .bower.json
    - jquery.js
    - ...
  - underscore
    - .bower.json
    - underscore.js
    - ...
  - ...
```

I wanted to ignore everything in `bower_components/` except `.bower.json` files, so I wrote such `.gitignore`:

```
bower_components/**/*
!bower_components/**/.bower.json
```

According to gitignore man git should ignore everything in sub directories of `bower_components` except `.bower.json` but it doesn't. I don't know what i'm doing wrong, I've tried different combinations including `!.bower.json` but with no luck.

`git check-ignore bower_components/jquery/.bower.json -v` gives me:

```
.gitignore:1:bower_components/**/*      bower_components/jquery/.bower.json
```

`ls bower_components/**/.bower.json` gives me list of `.bower.json` files.

I have a test tree to play with: nocorp.me/32430Z3J1o2k

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bug, maybe not, but I had to use single asterisks instead of double:

```
bower_components/*/*
!bower_components/*/.bower.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to not use the double-star in this situation.

```
!**/.bower.json
bower_components/*
```

Comment: Check my edit.  To me, this says don't ignore any file called `.bower.json`, then ignore everything under `bower_components`.

Comment: Still nothing. `git check-ignore bower_components/backbone/.bower.json -v` says `.gitignore:2:bower_components/* bower_components/backbone/.bower.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the case for you but ** is added in 1.8.2 so if you use anything older it's not going to work

```
git --version
```

Comment: I have a latest version from brew (git version 1.8.4.2)

Comment: I have 1.8.3.4 from homebrew too but that didn't helps it working